# Finding missing data in a sequence in MySQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Is there an efficient way to find missing data not just in one sequence, but many sequences?

This is probably unavoidably O(N**2), so efficient here is defined as relatively few queries using MySQL

Let's say I have a table of temporary employees and their starting and ending months.

```
employees  | start_month | end_month
------------------------------------
Jane         2017-05       2017-07
Bob          2017-10       2017-12
```

And there is a related table of monthly payments to those employees

```
employee | paid_month
---------------------
Jane       2017-05
Jane       2017-07
Bob        2017-11
Bob        2017-12
```

Now, it's clear that we're missing a month for Jane (2017-06) and one for Bob too (2017-10).

Is there a way to somehow find the gaps in their payment record, without lots of trips back and forth?

In the case where there's just one sequence to check, some people generate a temporary table of valid values, and then LEFT JOIN to find the gaps. But here we have different sequences for each employee.

One possibility is that we could do an aggregate query to find the COUNT() of paid_months for each employee, and then check it versus the expected delta of months. Unfortunately the data here is a bit dirty so we actually have payment dates that could be before or after that employee start or end date. But we're verifying that the official sequence definitely has payments.

Comment: i am confused , is the missing months are inserted in the database or just missing, if they are in database , i want to see the relation between tables so i can help, obviously there is two tables up there and there is a missing table for payment , am i right ?

Comment: it seems to me tell now that the problem is with the adding paid month for each temp employee

Comment: I would handle the logic of missing rows in application code

Answer (score 0):

Form a Cartesian product of employees and months, then left join the actual data to that, then the missing data is revealed when there is no matched payment to the Cartesian product.

You need a list of every months. This might come from a "calendar table" you already have, OR, it *MIGHT* be possible using a subquery if every month is represented in the source data)

e.g.

```
select
    m.paid_month, e.employee 
from (select distinct paid_month from payments) m
cross join (select employee from employees) e
left join payments p on m.paid_month = p.paid_month and e.employee = p.employee
where p.employee is null
```

The subquery `m` can be substituted by the calendar table or some other technique for generating a series of months. e.g.

```
select 
        DATE_FORMAT(m1, '%Y-%m')
from (
        select 
              '2017-01-01'+ INTERVAL m MONTH as m1
        from (
            select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as m 
            from (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t1
            cross join (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t2
            ## cross join (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t3
            ## cross join (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t4
            cross join(select @rownum:=-1) t0
            ) d1
        ) d2 
where m1 < '2018-01-01'
order by m1
```

The subquery `e` could contain other logic (e.g. to determine which employees are still currently employed, or that are "temporary employees")

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would work only if each employee is supposed to be paid during the same interval of months. The problem is that it's different every time, and the whole point is that we have "missing" months so we can't rely on it existing in the rows fetched.

Comment: If you used the query exactly as stated yes that would be true. However, as I mentioned, the subquery used to create the months can be tuned to whatever period is needed, and/or, the subquery to determine the list of employees can also be tuned. Your question contains no details about employee start and end dates, so neither does my answer but there is nothing stopping you from using such information in the query.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to get all the months between start date and end_date in a temporary table then need do a left outer join with the payments table on paid month filtering all non matching months ( payment employee name is null )

```
select e.employee, e.yearmonth as missing_paid_month from (
 with t as (
     select e.employee, to_date(e.start_date, 'YYYY-MM') as start_date, to_date(e.end_date, 'YYYY-MM') as end_date from employees e
  )
  select distinct t.employee, 
  to_char(add_months(trunc(start_date,'MM'),level - 1),'YYYY-MM') yearmonth
  from  t  
  connect by trunc(end_date,'mm') >= add_months(trunc(start_date,'mm'),level - 1)
  order by t.employee,  yearmonth
 ) e
left outer join payments p
on p.paid_month = e.yearmonth
where p.employee is null
```

output

```
EMPLOYEE    MISSING_PAID_MONTH
Bob         2017-10
Jane        2017-06
```

[SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b2857/35](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b2857/35)

Comment: Nice, except the OP doesn't mention ORACLE

Comment: @Strawberry yes, didn't see the tag, answer specific to Oracle 

Comment: Or the title, evidently :-(

Comment: This is ingenious! If I understand correctly, you're using a hierarchical query to create the table of months for each employee (each "level" is a recursion done within the database itself). Unfortunately this is MySQL.

Comment: @Neilk yes, it'll generate all months in between start and end month, and join with payments filtering all missing months